# Element to take up full height after css rotate

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a vertical progress bar by using a CSS transform. I want the progress bar to take up the full height of the screen.

The problem is that, since I use CSS rotate, the progress bar's height is equal to the *width* of the screen, not its height. I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyfbuhc9/9/) to demonstrate this: the length of the progress bar will change depending on how wide you make the 'Result' section. This is incorrect: it should always take up the entire screen. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<progress max="1" value="0.8"></progress>
```

CSS:

```
progress {
    margin: 0;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;

    /* Reset the default appearance */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;  
}
```

As it's a progress bar, its size cannot be larger than the screen height, otherwise the progress indication will be off. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838285/using-height-width-100-after-rotating-an-element-with-css) solution but this won't work for me because screen dimensions can change at anytime (e.g. switching between portrait and landscape on a tablet), so a JavaScript solution won't do.

Is there a way to force the progress bar to take up the full height of the screen using just CSS? Any other solution to create a vertical progress bar without using rotations, would also be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean, however try replacing `width:100%`, with `width:100vh;`.

Answer (score 0):

As @jaunt just said, using `width: 100vh` would do the trick, as it takes in consideration the viewport height to assign a width for the progress. Below you can find the list of browsers that support this:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units